# Pandas dataframe conditionally edit values based on other columns in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for pandas dataframe functions to conditionally edit values in a dataframe based on multiple conditions and search within the same data frame.
The table shown as follow should became as the one in the after with a binary code for each s1, s2, ...sn

The leading column is the 'start' column.

1. For each s if the value in the cell is 0 then the first binary digit is 0
2. If the value of 't' is in the 'start' column and for the s on the same row the value is 0 then the second binary digit is 0
3. when the value of s is > 0 then the binary digit is 1

Example:
index row 110
s1 > 0
look for value in 't', 7 in the 'start' column
nothing found(or == 0) then the value became '10'

index row 391
s2 > 0
5 is in 'start' at index 444 and s2 is > 0
then value become 11

The questions are:
Which is the most suitable pandas method to loop though each sample (s columns)?
And how can I locate the values from 't'  to the corresponding value in 'start'?
How do I check the '> 0' condition?

Note that this dataframe was built from a table with only start column and the samples (s1, s2, s3, .., sn), the 't' column has been added after a calculation but the values came from the 'start' column. Then there will be also possible to have indexes of the 't' values which will match the ones in start. In case could be more efficient with indexes then values.

before:

```
     start  t    s1     s2    s3
95      1   6     0     99    0
110     2   7    92      0    0
129     3   5     0      0    0
391     4   5     0     83   22
444     5   2    99     76    0
```

after:

```
     start  t    s1       s2    s3
95      1   6     00      10    00
110     2   7     10      00    00
129     3   5     01      00    00
391     4   5     01      11    10
444     5   2     10      10    00
```

Comment: Why is index 444 s2 "10" and not "11"? Also looks like the last three rows of s3 should be "01", "11", "01".

Comment: because at start value 5 in the table before there is a value (76) >0 in s2 column and if we look at the row 110 wiith start value 2 we have 0 in s2.

Comment: Imagine to have just the start column and the s columns, then a table were are defined the links within the values in the start column. From that I should build the after table.

Comment: Very confusing. Then why is index 444 s1 "10" and not "11"? At start 5, there is a 99 (>0) in s1 and row 110 also has a 92 in s1. Also row 129 s2 should be "01"? The s2 value in 129 is 0 and the s2 value in start 5 is 76.